# Diacritic characters are not rendered correctly in my browser

Tags: jquery, html, json, character-encoding

For internal test reporting, I created an HTML file that renders data onto the screen that is loaded through the JQuery Get method. The test data is in JSON format.

The problem I have is that data that contains diacritic characters (ï, ô, à etc.) isn't rendered correctly. This data string: `<{[Spécïàl Châr's!@&]>` is rendered into my reporting as `<{[Sp��Ch�s!@&]>`. The original string in the text file is correct displayed in notepad++.

Flow:

1. VBScript is creating a textfile through the filesystemobject,
   CreateTextFile method.
2. The txt file containing JSON strings is read
   by JQuery $.get into an array of JSON strings
3. Each JSON string is parsed by JQuery $.parseJSON into javascript objects
4. The objects are processed by JQuery to create a nice view

The HTML file where the data is rendered has the following meta data:

- `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; charset=UTF-8"/>`

I already tried to change the doctype into W3C doctypes, the content attribute to 'text/html' variants and the charset attribute to 'ISO-8859-1' variants but nothing seems to render my data correctly.

Could someone please give me a hint what I could do to detect in what part the problem resides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shooting in the dark here. Are you sure you have a unicode text file? Default encoding seems to be ASCII.
http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject_createtextfile.html

Comment: Aah, that's it. Never crossed my mind, I always thought it was the rendering part that went wrong, also because it seemed right in a text editor. Thank you for the hint, it is exactly what is the case.